# showModalBottomSheet not returning value when you are using it in a method

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a `String` that is supposed to be returned after clicking a button in a `Future` `showModalBottomSheet`. Below is how I am implementing it and how it is working:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  String? returnString = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
    context: context,
    isDismissible: false,
    builder: (ctx) {
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, setState) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(ctx, "This is return string bla bla bla");
            },
            child: Text("Click Me To Return"),
          ),
        );
      });
    },
  );

  Logger().i("PrintReturnString: $returnString");
  Logger().i("PrintReturnStringRunTimeType: ${returnString.runtimeType}");
}
```

But because I want to use this in several places and I did not want to repeat myself and rewrite the code every time in other classes that would be redundant I decided to try implementing this using a global method but its not working it just returns null instead of `String`:

> This is return string bla bla bla

Below is how I have tried implementing it using a method that I can call anywhere in the class:

```dart
showReturnStringBottomSheet(ctx) async {
  await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
    context: ctx,
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25))),
    elevation: 5,
    isDismissible: true,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (ctx) {
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, setState) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pop(ctx, "This is return string bla bla bla");
            },
            child: Text("Click Me To Return"),
          ),
        );
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Below is how I am calling the method:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  String? returnString = await showReturnStringBottomSheet(context);
}
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? because it's just working when I put the method directly inside `onPressed` but it stops working when I use a global method.

Comment: what do you mean use a global method?, where did you call it when its stop working?

Comment: I created a dart file called show_return_string_bottom_sheet and the method showReturnStringBottomSheet is inside the show_return_string_bottom_sheet  dart file. Even if i try using showReturnStringBottomSheet  in my same class its still not working, basically lets say when i use a method it stops working

Comment: if your class is a has a `context` it should be work. because `showBottomSheet` required context to render.

Answer (score 0):

`showModalBottomSheet` is an `async` method so you should wait for it then it makes your `showReturnStringBottomSheet` a `future` function ,Try this:

```
Future<String?> showReturnStringBottomSheet(ctx) async {
    var result = await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
        context: ctx,
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(25))),
        elevation: 5,
        isDismissible: true,
        isScrollControlled: true,
        builder: (ctx) {
          return StatefulBuilder(builder: (ctx, setState) {
            return Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(ctx, "This is return string bla bla bla");
                },
                child: Text("Click Me To Return"),
              ),
            );
          });
        });
    return result;
  }
```

and use it like this:

```
onPressed: () async {

   String? returnString = await showReturnStringBottomSheet(context);
   if(returnString != null){
      print("returnString = $returnString");
   }
 }
```

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out @EmmanuelNjorodongo

Comment: @EmmanuelNjorodongo does it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `String` outside your modal bottom sheet for example:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String? text;

  Future<void> _openBottomSheet() async {
    final value = await _myBottomSheet();
    setState(() {
      text = value;
    });
  }

  Future<String?> _myBottomSheet() async {
    String? value;

    await showModalBottomSheet<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {
            value = 'Hello world!';
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text('Say hello!'),
        ),
      ),
    );

    return value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: text?.isNotEmpty == true
            ? Text(text!)
            : const Text('Bottom sheet example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: _openBottomSheet,
          child: const Text('Open bottom sheet'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you forgot to return here:

```
showReturnStringBottomSheet(ctx) async {
  await showModalBottomSheet<String>(
```

change it to :

```
//Add Future<String?> here to make code cleaner
Future<String?> showReturnStringBottomSheet(ctx) { 
  return showModalBottomSheet<String>(
```